# How to make an introduction on related pages with Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I made documentation for a special project by using Doxygen, I have generated some related pages by using the following usage:

/**
 * @page xxx xxxx
 * @subpage yyyy
 * 
 * @page yyyy yyyy

the performance list as follows:
[image]

I want to add documentation in the rigth place, where I have tag it with red line.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@brief` command to add a short description of the page. E.g.:

```
/**
 * @page  page_tag_name Title of the Page
 * @brief This page describes blabla.
 */

/**
 * @page  second_page Title of the second page
 * @brief The second page describes...
 */
```

The result is that you will see the brief description on the right side.